# tar -xvf *.tar.gz gives me a weird name on extraction

Tags: linux, tar

I have a file "elasticsearch-servicewrapper.tar.gz". When I try to run:

```
tar -xvf elasticsearch-servicewrapper.tar.gz
```

I expect the extracted folder to be called "elasticsearch-elasticsearch-servicewrapper". But instead, I got "elasticsearch-elasticsearch-servicewrapper-d47d048". Is there a way I can force the target folder name?

This is on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: `tar` extracts files to the directory it finds itself in, with the filenames found in the archive. If the names in the archive start with "elasticsearch-elasticsearch-servicewrapper-d47d048/", then you can't easily prevent tar from creating that directory. Except perhaps symlink it to your desired location before untarring.

Comment: ... hmm, actually with GNU tar you can use `--strip-components 1` to make it ignore the first pathname element of each archived file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not up to tar - the directory is only created because it was inside the tarball anyway, so it has whatever name is stored inside the tarball.

You can make your own target folder and extract it into that using --strip-components to take off leading pathnames as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your just rename it by `mv elasticsearch-elasticsearch-servicewrapper-d47d048 elasticsearch-elasticsearch-servicewrapper` ?

You could try `tar -xvf elasticsearch-servicewrapper.tar.gz -C /tmp/elasticsearch-servicewrapper` too.

Comment: it's part of the puppet code, so I am trying to do something like:tar -xzf /tmp/elasticsearch-servicewrapper.tar.gz -C /tmp && mv /tmp/elasticsearch-servicewrapper /usr/local/elasticsearch-0.19.11/bin

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. See if that works.